# SQL ROW_NUMBER() problem with query after moving to Ubuntu

Tags: python, windows, sqlite, ubuntu

I have a problem with **near "(": syntax error** when moving my project to the server. Using VSC everything works, but after moving the project from Windows to Ubuntu after starting the program and calling the function the previously mentioned error pops up. Is there any solution to fix it? Maybe some equivalent of this query? I write the code in Python 3 and use SQLite3.

`cursor.execute(f"SELECT * FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY lvl DESC, exp DESC) AS rownumber, guild_id, user_id, lvl, exp FROM levels WHERE guild_id = '{ctx.guild.id}') WHERE user_id = {ctx.author.id}")`

Comment: Check which version of python you are using (`python --version`).  F-strings were introduced in Python3.5.

Comment: @snakecharmerb **3.8** This is probably due to ROW_NUMBER(). Everything else works, however, it probably triggers syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass all your variables as arguments

```
query = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY lvl DESC, exp DESC) " \
        "AS rownumber, guild_id, user_id, lvl, exp " \
        "FROM levels WHERE guild_id = %s) WHERE user_id = %s"
args = (ctx.guild.id,ctx.guild.id)

cursor.execute( query,args )
```

This method has security advantage like avoid sql injection.
You can read the documentation [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html)